# Multiple subscribe working in Rxjs 5.5.7 not working on RxjS 6.3.3

Tags: angular, rxjs6

`this.msService.createUpdate` is hitting 2 times and throwing error.
I have tried using take(1) but that is also not working.

```
  this.msService.save(this.ms).subscribe((ms: any) => {                   this.msService.getDataItemWithCalculations(String(this.DataItemId)).subscribe((calcs:any) => { //other manipulations                              this.msService.createUpdate(this.ms).subscribe(mswithChild => {
                       //service is hitting twice
                            this.msService.getDataItemWithCalculations(String(this.ms.DataItemUID)).subscribe(
                                (ms :any)=> {
                                    //other manipulations
                                this.setNotificationMessage();
                                }, error => this.setNotificationMessage();
                                  }, error => this.setNotificationMessage();
                                    }, error => this.setNotificationMessage();
                                      }, error => this.setNotificationMessage();
```

Comment: you should not nest multiple subscribe, but use `pipe` (since rxjs6), and the pipeable operators like `map` or `tap`

Comment: @Arikael how can I use pipe in the above scenario.Secondly, if this was working in Rxjs 5.5 why not 6.3? Also can u justify your answer  as to why we cannot use multiple subscribe?

Comment: @user1285143 There were breaking changes in version 6.0 you can check what changed here [Changelog](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: it's bad because you might end up with multiple, unwanted subscriptions, like in your case. (and it also makes code much more unreadable)

Have a look at https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html and https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

In your code what are `//other manipulations` doing?
Do they manipulate `this.ms`?

Comment: @Arikael yes there are manipulations with that object that is why there is a multiple subscribe because each time the result comes, we are performing some manipulations.

Comment: @JosefKatič those changes do not mention the above scenario.

Comment: please don't give me documentation link, i am very well aware of the usage of map. What i dont understand is what could be the cause and how I can fix it, or I need a workaround for the above scenario. As this is already written code, i need a good workaround

Comment: have you tried using map and mergeMap because your problem may very well be caused by your using of `subscribe`?

Comment: Also please note I am already using pipe in the service method. please re read the question before giving me documentation links. in the documentation it does not state how to use map with SUBSCRIBE

Comment: @user1285143, please paste valid code you're using and add [proper code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), e.g. \```lang-js ... \```.